# Matplotlib Funcanimation is visually inverting the Y limits of graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

First time posting a question, apologies if format is not great.

I am doing a 5-plot subplot using Pyplot and Funcanimation for a Tkinter app.  I have 180 seconds of data that I have set to a circular buffer to graph continuously (from csv file).  My issue is that on some of the graphs, the y limit numbers seem to be inverting or at least partially inverting.  For example, one plot should be (0,5) on the y limits, but when the values that are being graphed change from 0 to 5 (on/off) the graph limits are changing to (5,0) along with it and the graph visually inverts.  I have another subplot where there are 4 y limits ticks on the left, and only the bottom 2 invert so it is something like (0,600,680,700) --> (680,0,600,700).  Note: graph data is in .txt file as csv, not sure how to attach here.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

[image: Inverted Y axis limits and graph]

I am expecting the y limits to not invert on me.  The 0,5 should always be 0 on the bottom.  I'm using limits of (0,None) more specifically.

I am using autoscale and set_ylim to try to control the ticks, but it behaves oddly.  I used get_ylim() and yaxis_inverted() to see if the axes are actually changing, and though I'm using y_lim of (0,5) it reads out as (-0.05, 1.05) and always not inverted.

I've been searching online for a solution but not having any luck, only people looking to intentionally invert a graph.

I'm decent with Python, but not a developer (test engineer). I've used Matplotlib/Pyplot before, but this is my first time for Funcanimation.  I'm new to tkinter.  Here is code, shrunken to 2 axis to save space.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


#from PIL import Image, ImageTk


import csv
from tkinter.constants import *
from itertools import count
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


time = list(range(0,180))

# lists to make circular buffers for graphing
tempA, tempB, humA, humB = ([] for _ in range(10)) 

#read in data from file into a list of lists, eventually replace with reading in serial data
with open("C:\\temp\\Visual Studio Code\\.vscode\\tkinter practice\\DDMI_practice_data.txt", "r", newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        
        tempA.append(row[0])
        tempB.append(row[1])
        humA.append(row[2])
        humB.append(row[3])


########################################
###########      graphs      ###########
########################################

#Get all axes of figure
a = plt.gcf()

def animate(i):

    ax1, ax2 = a.get_axes()
    
    # Clear current data
    ax1.cla()
    ax2.cla()

    # set y limits
    ax1.set_ylim(69.65,None)
    ax2.set_ylim(0,None)
    
    # set Y tick marks
    ax1.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LinearLocator(4))
    ax2.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LinearLocator(4))
    
    # set X tick marks
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(30))
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(30))
    
    # turn on auto scaling
    ax1.autoscale(enable=True)
    ax2.autoscale(enable=True)
    
    # make circular by removing the first value and moving it to the back of the list
    time.pop(0); time.append(float(i)+179)
    aa=tempA.pop(0); tempA.append(aa)
    bb=tempB.pop(0); tempB.append(bb)
    cc=humA.pop(0); humA.append(cc)
    dd=humB.pop(0); humB.append(dd)
    

    # Set graph titles
    ax1.set_title("Temperature"); ax1.set_ylabel("deg C")
    ax2.set_title("Humidity");  ax2.set_ylabel("percent")
    
    # plot the graphs
    ax1.plot(time, tempA, "darkorange" ); 
    ax1.plot(time, tempB, "blue" ); 
    ax2.plot(time, humA, "darkorange" ); 
    ax2.plot(time, humB, "blue" ); 
    

    print(ax2.get_ylim())
    print(ax2.yaxis_inverted())

root = tk.Tk()

# GUI
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(plt.gcf(), master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="NSEW")


# Create five subplots
plt.gcf().subplots(2,1)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.8)

# Generate the animations
ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=200, blit=False)
#plt.show()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Holey Cow, problem solved.  Talked it through with a coworker and he found something that said that the data in the lists to be plotted had issues when it was strings, and I had it as strings since it was read in from a csv file.  Apparently, there is an issue with the limits ending up out of order if the data in the list is numbers in string form.  I switched the "row[0]" to "float(row[0])", and that took care of the issue.

Comment: also, side comment: it is good practice, for clarity, to avoid wildcard imports:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0) pollute the namespace.